# pentaho kettle javascript logging

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle

I'm a pentaho noob using kettle/spool 5.1.  I have a javascript step and I want to write to the log.  I've tried writeToLog('testing') and writeToLog('r','testing') and I never get 'testing' out in the logging window (which I have selected to show record level logging).  Any thoughts about what I'm doing wrong?  Basically I just want to print out a value (in the middle of my JS function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.  I was setting the log level in the logging window pulldown but not setting the log level in my Launch window.